# Windows 7 - Run Devices and Printers as Different User

Tags: windows-7, windows, printer, administrator, control-panel

So at my work we have to install and remove printers pretty often and most users do not have admin privileges on their PCs. I've been looking into trying to run the Devices and Printers applet as admin to avoid having to switch user to the admin account.

What I've done so far:

Ran cmd as another user (my admin account) > control printers > still not opening with admin creds.

However if I type mmc, it will let me access computer management as admin.

Anyone know if this is possible under Windows 7?